# Python Loop to add random number until at least 20

Tags: python, while-loop, sum

I need some help with a loop assignment, I am trying to select random values until they add to or are greater than 20. I also need to show how many times the loop ran to be true.

```
import random
n = random.randint(0,9)
total_numbers = n
sum = 20
while n >= 0:
    sum += n
    n -= 1
print("sum =", sum)
```

so far im getting the value great than 20 but i am not sure if i did the loop correctly and how to show the loop counts.

Comment: No, that's not correct.  You only pick ONE random number, and then you add up all the numbers from 1 to that number, plus 20.  You will always get > 20, because you START with 20.  Clearly, you have to start with `sum = 0`, and your while loop needs to run until `sum > 20`.  In the loop, you add a random number to `sum`.  The other variables are not useful.

Comment: you need a counter variable that also starts at 0. You add 1 to it every time you add a random number to the `sum`.

Comment: BTW, don't use `sum` as a variable name, you're overwriting a built-in function.

Comment: @TimRoberts They wrote "I also need to show how many times the loop ran"

Comment: "I am trying to select random values until they add to or are greater than 20." In your own words, what should the code look like, in order to describe that idea? Is there anything in your code to try to check that? Where the code says `while n >= 0:`, what do you expect this to mean? In your program, what does the variable `sum` represent? What does the variable `n` represent? What does the variable `total_numbers` represent? Step by step, how do you think the logic should work?

Comment: If you want to have a loop that adds numbers until the sum is at least 20: what do you think should happen each time through the loop? How should you know when to stop looping?

Answer (score -1):

Based on your description, I don't think your code does what it's supposed to, no. I don't want to tell you exactly what's wrong, since I think it's better for you to learn to find out yourself.

Try adding this print:

```
print('added', n, 'to sum, which is now', sum)
```

Make sure you add it immediately after the `sum +=` line, before `n` changes.

Then run your program and see if the steps your program reports match what you expected.

Here are two runs I did:

```
tmp$ python3 test.py 
added 7 to sum, which is now 27
added 6 to sum, which is now 33
added 5 to sum, which is now 38
added 4 to sum, which is now 42
added 3 to sum, which is now 45
added 2 to sum, which is now 47
added 1 to sum, which is now 48
added 0 to sum, which is now 48
sum = 48

tmp$ python3 test.py 
added 3 to sum, which is now 23
added 2 to sum, which is now 25
added 1 to sum, which is now 26
added 0 to sum, which is now 26
sum = 26
```

Now, consider these questions:

- Is the loop running until `sum` is at least 20?
- Is the loop ending as soon as `sum` is at least 20?
- Are you selecting random numbers to add?

Finally, to count the number of loops:

- create a variable that starts at 0
- increase it by 1 each loop
- at the end, it will have counted the number of iterations in your loop

Answer (score -1):

Right now, what your code says is this: Get a random number and we will add that many numbers together, storing them in a variable named sum. You don't change n each time, so you add the same random number as what you initialized the loop with. You initialized sum with 20, which means whatever random n numbers you add to sum will always be greater than 20, of course.

So, sum is a reserved Python keyword for the built-in function, it might be confusing to use as a variable for many, I would just use `s` or `_sum`.

I'm going to give you the answer so you can reflect on the differences, consider what you're telling us you want to do. You want to add numbers until you get to 20, then tell us how many additions it took:

```
import random

times = 0
_sum = 0
while _sum <= 20:
    times += 1
    # Get a new random number each time
    _sum += random.randint(0, 9)

# print how many times it took to get to 20
print(times)
```

For your own interest, ask follow up questions to confirm your understanding of your prior misinterpretation.

Comment: `sum` is **not** "restricted" (perhaps you meant "reserved"? that would at least be a meaningful term in context, but the claim would still be incorrect) and the behaviour is **not** undefined. It is simply a pre-defined built-in function. Using that variable name simply shadows it, which is typically undesirable but is legal and has perfectly predictable results. Python just doesn't *do* "undefined behaviour", at least if you aren't messing with it at the bytecode level or the C-extension level.

Comment: Gotcha, will amend the wording. I'll still pretend using reserved keywords is as hazardous as anything undefined, personally.